# Align Menu items vertically in center

Tags: android, xml

I have a menu with fragment (the screen of each menu's item). I need to align this items in center vertically.

There's my code:

activity_maps.xml (the screen of 'map' item)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".HomeFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the menu_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There's the activity_main with the menu which has some menu_itens.xml inside a listView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Edit: print link 
http://s12.postimg.org/3ysbeaarx/Screenshot_2015_03_06_10_35_53.png

Comment: Please add some more information. what are you trying to achieve, a great way is to add a screen capture. also maybe add what is the result of the code you wrote so far

Comment: @royb please, see my edit with the screen capture

Answer (score 0):

you can use this **LinearLayout** instead of **ListView**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

or u can redesign as u like with any layout